# I must prove that $\lim_{\mu(A)\rightarrow 0}\int_{A}\lvert f \lvert{\rm d}\mu=0$.

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

I am attempting to prove that $$\lim_{\mu(A)\rightarrow 0}\int_{A}\lvert f \lvert {\rm d}\mu=0.$$

> Given $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measured space , we suppose that $$f\in L^{1}(X,\mathcal{M},\mu) \text{ prove that } \displaystyle\lim_{\mu(A)\rightarrow 0}\int_{A}\lvert f \lvert{\rm d}\mu=0\text{ with } \mu \text{ a positive measure}$$

My attempt: we put $\lvert f \lvert=g\ge 0$ then there exists $g_{n}$  an increasing sequence of positive simple function such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g_{n}(x)=g(x)$ and:
$$g_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_{i}^{n}\chi_{A_{i}^{n}} \text{ where }A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}A_{i}^{n} \text{ and }  A_{i}^{n}\cap A_{j}^{n}=\emptyset \text{ if } i\neq j \implies \int_{A}g_{n}{\rm d}\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_{i}^{n}\mu({A_{i}^{n}})$$
and because $\mu(A)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N}\mu(A_{i}^{n}) \text{ then } \mu(A)\rightarrow 0 \iff \mu(A_{i}^{n})\rightarrow 0 , \forall i\in\{1,2,...,N\}  $ then:
$$\lim_{\mu(A)\rightarrow 0}\int_{A}g_{n}{\rm d}\mu=0$$
by the monotone convergence theorem we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{A}g_{n}{\rm d}\mu=\int_{A}{\rm d}\mu$ we can deduce in this case that:
$$\lim_{\mu(A)\rightarrow 0}\int_{A}g{\rm d}\mu=0$$
but I am not sure of this answer.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: just use the dominated convergence theorem, noticing that $f$ is integrable

Comment: @Masacroso how do I do that , and in what step?

Comment: @Xavier just set $g_A:=\mathbf{1}_{A}|f|$, then for any chosen $A$ you have that $g_A\leqslant |f|$, therefore the dominated convergence theorem give us $\lim_{\mu (A)\to 0}\int g_A=\int \lim_{\mu (A)\to 0}g_A=\int 0=0$

Comment: @Masacroso I dont understand how we can introduce the limite inside the integrale if we dont have a sequence of mesurable fonctions

Comment: @XavierRaymond there is a characterization of functional limits in term of limit of sequences, take a look [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-sequential-criterion-for-a-limit-of-a-function)

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry I still can't see the connexion and I'am still trying to know if the answer i gave is correct.

Comment: @Xavier sorry, I didnt see that you want a verification of your proposed solution, however your solution is not correct or at less incomplete, as far as I can see you are mixing the sets that define the sequence $(g_n)$ that converges to $g$ and a sequence of measurable sets $(A_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\mu (A_n)=0$. What it seems that you are trying to show is that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int\mathbf{1}_{A_n}g_n=0$, however this is not what you need to prove, or it is not clear what is it relation to the statement of the exercise.

Comment: Call me crazy, but if you know monotone convergence theorem, don't you also know dominated convergence theorem? I see that one may try to prove it without invoking these theorems, but if you are going to use them, resorting to simple functions is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider a large quantity $\alpha$. Now,
$$\int_A |f| d\mu = \int_{|f| \leq\alpha} |f| I_A d\mu  + \int_{|f| \geq\alpha} |f|I_A d\mu  $$
$$ \leq \alpha \mu(A) + \int_{|f| \geq\alpha} |f|I_A d\mu $$

Now, $|f|I_{A \cap \{|f| \geq\alpha\}} < \epsilon$ for large $\alpha$.
Therefore, 
$$
\int_{|f| \geq\alpha} |f|I_A d\mu < \epsilon \mu(A \cap \{|f| \geq\alpha\}) < \epsilon \mu(A)
$$

So,
$$
\int_A |f| d\mu \leq \alpha \mu(A) + \epsilon \mu(A)
$$
Take $\mu(A) \rightarrow 0$ both side,you get the desired result.